# Display "migrated to meta" instead of "closed" in migrated questions' titles

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, questions, migration, title

When an SO question is clearly a candidate for Meta, I have to go read it to see if it was only closed, or migrated to where it belongs. Can't the text say **[migrated to meta]** instead of **[closed]** when that's what has happened?

Comment: +1 because "(this q isn't closed!)" amuses me

Comment: Coming back to this a year later, I find that title to be kinda confusing. I've edited it out; it's against policy now, anyways. (But I'm not un-upvoting).

Comment: another idea ahead of its time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This would require denormalizing the value, which isn't worth it IMO.

Clicking through will show you exactly what happened.

edit: we did eventually denormalize this as MigrationDate, and there are lots more migrations now that we have 40+ sites, so -- implemented as `[migrated]` on questions instead of just plain `[closed]`.

Comment: What it means *denormalizing the value*?

Comment: @Tshepang, data is stored in many different database tables, and to get or calculate some details, many tables must be combined (joined) to get that. That might be slow, and therefore some details might not be available on pages that are requested by many visitors. To speed up things, some data might be kind of duplicated and then a copy of, for example, the last migration date can be stored in the same database table that holds details such as question title and body. (Likewise each vote is known, so the total score can be calculated. But the total itself is also stored for quick access.)