# If a question is migrated, say so in the title

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, migration, title

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Display “migrated to meta” instead of “closed” in migrated questions' titles](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/display-migrated-to-meta-instead-of-closed-in-migrated-questions-titles)

On a site's main page, a migrated question is titled like *Blah blah [closed]*. Can you replace *Closed* with *Migrated*.