# Migrated question still showing [​closed] in question page on original site, instead of [​migrated]

Tags: bug, status-completed, question-lists, migrated-questions

Migrated question still showing **[closed]** in question page, instead it should show **[migrated]**

[image]

**ps**: currently at [page 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?page=5&sort=newest#question-summary-5615583), but will go away to older page eventually.

Comment: probably one of the toxic side effects [Jeff mentioned](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10641/instead-of-closed-for-migrated-questions-migrated/86797#86797)

Comment: I kind of doubt that, @Tobias, given that some lists show it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has been resolved; it should be fixed in the next build. It was a simple omission from a particular code path that fed this display.

Comment: I think I just observed the mentioned effect on [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512177/computer-science-minor) question. First time I saw it it was shown as `[migrated]` in the list, but then I came across it again and it was listed as `[closed]`. I thought the migration was reverted (saw it once) but that was not the case.

Answer (score 2):

And: while `/questions` may be wrong:

[image: Incorrectly showing closed, not migrated]

...the Top Questions on the homepage get it right for the very same question:

[image: Correctly showing migrated]

...and so does [the question itself](https://serverfault.com/questions/257991/remote-access-of-powerful-pc-does-not-work?noredirect=1), and so do the 10k tools.

(I'd guess some piece of code that renders blocks with an excerpt has been forgotten in [this change](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6022/display-migrated-to-meta-instead-of-closed-in-migrated-questions-titles/6025#6025)?)